Presale token claim - node problem
i really need your skilled guidance... I bought some tokens in a presale and since I am not a professional and it was not clearly indicated from the start, I selected one of the two options to purchase the token: BNB. Maybe most of you would have known that this will/could lead to some trouble (there was no warning or anything!!). After looking into other presale projects and getting more info it became clear to me that it would have been absolutely crucial to buy the token with ETH since it is an ERC-20 token. Now claim day has passed and I am trying everything to be able to "solve the node problem" as the "admins" phrased it and claim my purchase. Apart from the fact that this project was most likely a scam (but that isnt the issue here, unless someone would like to know) I am now curious if there are ANY possibilities at all to claim a token from a presale initially bought on BEP-20 and now solely issued via ERC-20. I treid several multichain wallets, integrated the bnb and try to connect to the token claim page... but the page doesnt recognize it so my tokens arent even shown. Is there any way to do this? Another question out of curiosity: I saw that many presale projects offer different purchasing methods...why would they even do that when purchasing wallet has to be identical with the wallet I later claim my token with? Last question: I noticed tow different ways of selling in the ICO...most of the time it is with a smart contract that automatically deducts the funds from your connected wallets. Others generate an QR code (wallet address) to send the funds to. Why would any developer chose that option? If it's a scam, ok! I see why this would help. But let's imagine for a second it is not a scam (for example doge kombat does it like that, but they have a KYC verified report)... why would someone do this? is it cheaper maybe? More flexibility?  But wouldnt that mean you would have to send the tokens from presale manually to the investors? Please help me ! Thank you so much in advance!

Each presale is unique there isn't a standard way to get funding. You should not invest in a project that doesn't provide enough information how it will work. Usually serious projects go beyond the basics to help its supporters. Unfortunately in your case the project seems to be a scam, or lazy people. Using a unique addresses was commonly used for projects that accepted BTC. It has some advantages (easy to use for centralized wallets), and some problems (extra fee needed to consolidate balances).

thank you, Ismael! ☹️
